# Show that $\exists x \in I$ such that: $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, the set $\left\{s \in S \colon |s-x|<\frac{1}{n}\right\}$ is infinite

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I'm trying to solve this homework:

Let $I = [a,b]$, real closed bounded interval where $a<b$. Let $S \subset I$ s.t $S$ is infinite. Show that $\exists x \in I$ such that: $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, the set $\left\{s \in S \colon |s-x|<\frac{1}{n}\right\}$ is infinite.

I'm planning to answer by using definition of density. Since $I$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, one can affirm that $\forall X \subset I$, $I \cap X \neq \emptyset$. But how can I show that exists a specific x that solves the question? And must I demonstrate $I$ is dense, isn't it dense by construction?

Edit: I cannot use definitions from sequences, series nor topology. I can use until theorems and definitions from Field, Nested Interval Theorem, Interval, Supremum/Infimum, Archimedean property...

Comment: $I$ is a real closed bounded interval. It is not dense in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1718788/proving-every-bounded-infinite-set-has-a-limit-point-without-using-bolzano-weier

Comment: What tools do you have at your disposal? Depending on what you know, this could be trivial or it could be used to prove these grander theorems.

Comment: I cannot use definitions from sequences, series nor topology. What I can use are theorems and definitions from Field, Nested Interval Theorem, Interval, Supremum/Infimum, Archimedean property...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Successive bisection method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368888/successive-bisection-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $S$ is infinite in the compact segment $I=[a,b]$, $S$ has at least a limit point $x \in I$. $x$ answers the question.

Other proof using Nested Interval Theorem:

- As $S$ is infinite, $[a, \frac{a+b}{2}] \cap S$ or $[\frac{a+b}{2}, b] \cap S$ is infinite. Select for $I_1$ the interval for which the intersection is infinite.
- Proceed in a similar way to define from $I_n$ an interval $I_{n+1}$which length is the half of the one of $I_n$ and such that $I_{n+1} \cap S$ is infinite.
- Select $x \in \cap_{n \in \mathbb N} I_n$ which exists according to the Nested Interval Theorem.

Some additional remarks:

- $I$ is not dense in $\mathbb R$. For example $2\sup(\vert a \vert , \vert b \vert)$ is not a limit point of $I$.
- $S$ may not be dense in $I$. For example if $I=[-1,1]$ and $S = \{1/n \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$.

Comment: Is there a way to answer without using definitions from Topology? Maybe by using Nested Interval Theorem on $S$ and showing that $S$ has at least an element?

Comment: See updated answer using Nested Interval theorem.

Comment: Hey, thank you! And would you be so kind to give me some guideline to how to prove that this $x \in \cap_{n \in \mathbb N} I_n$ is the $x$ with the property that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ $\left\{s \in S \colon |s-x|<\frac{1}{n}\right\}$ is infinite? Without using limit point definition. Kept trying solve this since yesterday but I'm not sure.

Comment: Take an interval $I_k$ that contains $x$ and that has a length less than $1/n$. Remember that $I_k$ contains an infinite number of points in $S$.

Answer (score 2):

We shall use Bolzano-Weierstrass compactness.

Let $X$ be a metric space.Then $X$ is compact iff every infinite subset of $X$ has a limit point.

$I=[a,b]$ is a compact interval and $S\subset I$ is an infinite subset.So,$S$ has a limit point in $I$ .Let $x\in I$ be the point.

Then $x$ is a limit point of $S$ and hence for each $n\in \mathbb N$,we have $B(x,\frac{1}{n})\cap S$ infinite i.e. $\{x\in S: |x-s|<\frac{1}{n}\}$ is infinite for each $n\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Sadly I cannot use this theorem yet, but thank you for your answer!